# Proving an identity with sums

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I would like to prove the identity $$\forall n\in\mathbb N_0,\;k\in\lbrace0,1,\ldots,n\rbrace:\sum_{m=k}^{n+1}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n+1}{m}\cdot\frac{2(n+1-m)}{n+1-k}=\sum_{m=k}^{n+1}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n+1}{m}.$$
Since the first two factors in the sum don't change, this should be equivalent to proving $$\forall n\in\mathbb N_0,\;k\in\lbrace0,1,\ldots,n\rbrace,\;a_m\in\mathbb R:\sum_{m=k}^{n+1}a_m\cdot\frac{2(n+1-m)}{n+1-k}=\sum_{m=k}^{n+1}a_m.$$
I haven't got any helpful idea except we can leave out the case $m=n+1$ in the left sum as the numerator of the fraction gets $0$ in that case.

Any clues are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that

$${m\choose k} {n+1\choose m}
= \frac{(n+1)!}{k! (m-k)! (n+1-m)!}
= {n+1\choose k} {n+1-k\choose n+1-m}.$$

so that the equality becomes

$$2 {n+1\choose k} \sum_{m=k}^{n+1} 
{n+1-k\choose n+1-m}
\frac{n+1-m}{n+1-k}
= {n+1\choose k} \sum_{m=k}^{n+1} 
{n+1-k\choose n+1-m}.$$

This means we seek

$$2 \sum_{m=k}^{n} 
{n-k\choose n-m}
= \sum_{m=k}^{n+1} 
{n+1-k\choose n+1-m}$$

because the LHS term is zero when $m=n+1.$

The equality is equivalent to

$$2 \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} 
{n-k\choose n-m-k}
= \sum_{m=0}^{n+1-k} 
{n+1-k\choose n+1-m-k}$$

which is

$$2 \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} 
{n-k\choose m}
= \sum_{m=0}^{n+1-k} 
{n+1-k\choose m}$$

so we get at the end

$$2\times 2^{n-k} = 2^{n+1-k}$$

which certainly holds.